# Apache Hadoop pig SPLIT not working. Giving Error 1200

Tags: hadoop, split, apache-pig, latin

Structure of bag:

```
emp = LOAD '...../emp.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS
      (ename:chararray,id:int,job:chararray,sal:double)
```

This bag contains details of employees. I want to split the data based on job.

```
Bag = split emp into mngr if job == 'MANAGER';
```

This is not working & giving `Error 1200.`

If I include one more condition with it, `for ex.- sal10k if sal<10000`, then it is working. But why not only on one `chararray`?

I am new to hadoop pig. Know few basics. Kindly help.

Comment: As per this http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html#Case+Sensitivity, it may be the case creating problem. Try Bag = SPLIT emp INTO mngr IF job == 'MANAGER';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly find the solution to the problem below along with basic explanation about SPLIT operator:

1. The SPLIT operator is used to break a relation into ***two new relations***. So you need to take care of both conditions , like IF and ELSE:
   **For instance:** IF(Something matches) then make Relation1, IF(NOT(something
   matches) then make another relation. ( You don't have else keyword in Pig).
2. SPLIT operation is an independent operation, meaning that you cant store the SPLIT operation in a relation:

Example:
Bag = split emp into mngr if job == 'MANAGER';   // This is wrong.

You can't represent a SPLIT operation by a relation.
It will execute independently on the GRUNT shell or Script like this :

*SPLIT emp INTO managers IF(job MATCHES '.*MANAGER.*'),not_managers IF(NOT(job MATCHES '.*MANAGER.*'));*

Here is an example data set and output for your reference:
**

- ***Dataset***

**

```
Ron,1331,MANAGER,7232332.34
John,4332,ASSOCIATE,45534.6
Michell,4112,MANAGER,8342423.43
Tamp,1353,ASSOCIATE,34324.67
Ramo,2144,MODULE LEAD,845433.32
Shina,1389,MANAGER,8345321.78
Chin,4323,MODULE LEAD,455465.42
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
emp = LOAD 'stackfile.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ename:chararray,id:int,job:chararray,sal:double);

SPLIT emp INTO managers IF(job MATCHES '.*MANAGER.*'),not_managers IF(NOT(job MATCHES '.*MANAGER.*'));

DUMP managers;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(Ron,1331,MANAGER,7232332.34)
(Michell,4112,MANAGER,8342423.43)
(Shina,1389,MANAGER,8345321.78)
```

Comment: Wow.. This worked.. Thanks a lot.. You saved the day for me..:-)

Comment: @user1716991 If CodeReaper's answer worked for you, then you should upvote and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SPLIT operator wrong.
This is from doc:
SPLIT alias INTO alias IF expression, alias IF expression [, alias IF expression …] [, alias OTHERWISE];

So don't use this part "Bag =" at start.